# Problems with read() and readObject()

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth

I try to develop a card game to play 1vs1 via Bluetooth. I have connected the devices, and now I have a problem: I want to send Objects throw the Bluetooth.
If I make only Objects, it works, if only Strings, it works. 
But if I try to make both at the same time, I have problems.

```
/**
 * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
 * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
 */
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    // for Objects
    private final ObjectInputStream mObjectInStream;
    private final ObjectOutputStream mObjectOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
        mmSocket = socket;

        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        ObjectInputStream tmpObjIn = null;
        ObjectOutputStream tmpObjOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();

            tmpObjOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            tmpObjOut.flush();
            tmpObjIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }


        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;

        mObjectOutStream = tmpObjOut;
        mObjectInStream = tmpObjIn;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (D) Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;


        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {

                try {

                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                    BluetoothService.this.start();
                    break;
                }

                try {

                    // Send the obtained Object to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ_OBJECT, -1, -1, mObjectInStream.readObject())
                            .sendToTarget();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                    BluetoothService.this.start();
                    break;
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException cn) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Class not found", cn);
                }
            }

    }


    /**
     * Write to the connected OutStream.
     *
     * @param buffer The bytes to write
     */

    public void writeString(byte[] buffer) {
        try {

            mmOutStream.write(buffer);

            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write an Object (Serializable) to the connected OutStream.
     *
     * @param object The object to write
     */
    public void writeObject(Object object) {
        try {

            mObjectOutStream.writeObject(object);

            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity

            // TODO hier unterscheiden zwischen Player und UnoKarte?
            mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_WRITE_OBJECT, -1, -1, object)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }


    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
06-21 14:18:44.580  10941-11034/? E/BluetoothService﹕ disconnected
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Wrong format: 0
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.corruptStream(ObjectInputStream.java:830)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:943)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2262)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2217)
        at com.example.thm_wip1.uno.BluetoothService$ConnectedThread.run(BluetoothService.java:550)
```

line 550 is:`mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ_OBJECT, -1, -1, mObjectInStream.readObject()`)

---

In the `While(true)` I have two try-catch, in first I try to read string and in the second my Object. How can I differentiate between String and Objects in the run-method?
I'm new to sockets, `inputStream`, `outputStream`..

If you need more details, I edit will edit my question.

Comment: this can actually be caused by multiple things, showing us your code this way is not very useful, can you show us your function calls to writeObject and how you instantiate the class? -EDIT I found your problem I believe.

Answer (score -1):

StreamCorruptedException happens when you have header reading inconsistency in the device's internal consistency checks, in your case the consistency check is failing because you are trying to use multiple outputstreams and inputstreams, the first ones are defined in tmpout and tmpin and then you try to create ObjectOutputStreams and ObjectinputStreams from different outputstreams and inputstreams again. These cause header inconsistency.

The correct code that should fix this is as follows

```
 try {
        tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
        tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();

        tmpObjOut = new ObjectOutputStream(tmpOut);
        tmpObjOut.flush();
        tmpObjIn = new ObjectInputStream(tmpIn);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what he is already doing. Multiple streams would cause `invalid type code: AC`.

Comment: @EJP if you clearly look at his code, vs my code, it ISN'T the same thing, he is calling socket.getInputStream() twice, once in tmpIn, and another time in tmpObjIn, which is WHY he has a corrupt bluetooth stream. This is the solution to that guy's code, tested and thorough. Read the code carefully please before you downvote :).