# Bluetooth Connection with two devices (stream)

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth, stream

I develop a card game and want to pass different Objects, String to the connected device (Bluetooth) and back. 
The devices are connected.
The question is: how is this possible? I tried with only strings: it worked, only one object (example: Card): worked, but if I try both at same time, the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is crashed? Can you provide you code example, exception and stacktrace? It would be very helpful.

What can I suppose - if you can't access device concurrently you can use java monitors (synchronized keyword) to ensure that only one thread works with device at the same time. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html can

Comment: I asked a question today, but here I wanted some info how it is possible. But here my previous question: hope its what you needet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964524/problems-with-read-and-readobject