# Input-/OutputStream problems in the run

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth

I try to differentiate in the run method from my Connected-thread what I want to read. Now I want to read a String and an own class (UnoCard).

If I only send Strings, its fine, only my class: fine. Now I have to send different Objects and Strings at the same time.

How is this possible?

Please help me, I try to do this for days

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    private final ObjectInputStream mObjectInStream;
    private final ObjectOutputStream mObjectOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
        mmSocket = socket;

        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        ObjectInputStream tmpObjIn = null;
        ObjectOutputStream tmpObjOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();


            tmpObjOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            tmpObjOut.flush();
            tmpObjIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());


        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }


        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;

        mObjectOutStream = tmpObjOut;
        mObjectInStream = tmpObjIn;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (D) Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;


        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {

            if (mStateObject == STATE_STRING) {
                try {

                    Log.d(TAG, "StateObject: " + mStateObject);

                    if (mmInStream.available() > 0) {
                        // Read from the InputStream
                        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                        // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                        mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                                .sendToTarget();
                    }

                    Thread.sleep(2000);


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                    BluetoothService.this.start();
                    break;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (mStateObject == STATE_OBJECT) {
                try {

                    if (mObjectInStream.available() > 0) {

                        // Read from the InputStream
                        UnoCard card = (UnoCard) mObjectInStream.readObject();

                        // Send the obtained Object to the UI Activity
                        mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ_OBJECT, -1, -1, card)
                                .sendToTarget();
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(2000);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                    BluetoothService.this.start();
                    break;
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException cn) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Class not found", cn);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }



    /**
     * Write to the connected OutStream.
     *
     * @param buffer The bytes to write
     */

    public void writeString(byte[] buffer) {
        try {

            mmOutStream.write(buffer);

            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write an Object (Serializable) to the connected OutStream.
     *
     * @param object The object to write
     */
    public void writeObject(Object object) {
        try {
            mObjectOutStream.writeObject(object);
            mObjectOutStream.flush();

            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity

            mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_WRITE_OBJECT, -1, -1, object)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }


    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't make much sense. You can't predict what's coming over the socket based on local state. It would be simpler to just read the object and see what it is, with `instanceof`. And get rid of the `available()` test and the sleep. It is literally a waste of time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with read() and readObject()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964524/problems-with-read-and-readobject)